# while importing Flask TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev

using python 3.8, flask 1.1.2

When using pycharm debug bug mode found out that when I import `from flask_restful import Api` it outputs the error.

Weird thing is that everything worked fine and all of a sudden error arises. Also code still runs after error arises.

I've read other related post however still not understanding it.

full code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api
```

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/238/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 169, in _get_type
    if resolver.can_provide(type_object, type_name):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/238/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd_plugins/extensions/types/pydevd_plugin_numpy_types.py", line 28, in can_provide
    return nd_array is not None and issubclass(type_object, nd_array)
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: traceback shows that this is [a bug in Pycharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-43902)